# What is the Gibbs free energy change of physisorption?

Tags: thermodynamics

In most sites I find online, I see that the [Gibbs free energy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gibbs_free_energy) of adsorption is negative. But, it is also said that physisorption is a reversible adsorption, suggesting that $\delta G=0$ which contradicts the original premise.

Hence, what exactly is the correct free energy change associated with physisorption?

From comments I learn that the reversibility is not used in the conventional thermodynamics sense but rather in the chemical reaction sense [(refer)](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/41414/when-is-a-reaction-reversible). But, I don't see how it applies here since physisorption doesn't involve any bond formation.

---

[NCERT chapter](https://ncert.nic.in/ncerts/l/lech105.pdf) claiming the $\delta G = 0$ and reversibility condition

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/128801/discussion-on-question-by-buraian-what-is-the-gibbs-free-energy-change-of-physis).